# MKMapView not showing on device

Tags: iphone, devise, mkmapview

I have a little problem and i dont know why is it happening.

My map view is woking fine in the simulator but on the real device I only see the pin on the gray area and the "google" logo. It's like the images cant be loaded, it look like when you zoom in and you wait for the view to draw around the square.

Here is my code, I would appreciate any help

```
#import "Maps.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"


@implementation AddressAnnotation

@synthesize coordinate;
-(NSString *) subtitle{
    return @"327 Anzac Parade, Wodonga, Victoria, Australia";
}
-(NSString *) title{
    return @"Blazing Stump";
}
-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) c{
    coordinate = c;
    NSLog(@"%f,%f",c.latitude, c.longitude);
    return self;
}

@end


@implementation Maps

-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) addressLocation{

    NSString *locationString =  [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=327%20Anzac%20Parade,%20Wodonga,%20Victoria,%20Australia&output=csv&key=ABQIAAAAZs2zFXiuKBFeLpPgSfgMjBTHxw17-t8q3X3AgrE9NufATyE8MRRmwlyLMPtOSzliJQntEtaZ7T-Rww"]
                                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSArray *listItems = [locationString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    double latitude = -36.139226;
    double longitude = 146.911454;
    if ([listItems count] >=4 && [[listItems objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"200"]){
        latitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];
        longitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue];
    }else {
        //some error
    }
    CLLocationCoordinate2D  location;
    location.latitude = latitude;
    location.longitude = longitude;
    return location;

}
-(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{
    MKPinAnnotationView *annView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];
    annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
    annView.animatesDrop = TRUE;
    annView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);
    return annView;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta=0.2;
    span.longitudeDelta=0.2;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location = [self addressLocation];
    region.span=span;
    region.center=location;

    if(addAnnotation != nil) {
        [mapView removeAnnotation:addAnnotation];
        [addAnnotation release];
        addAnnotation = nil;
    }

    addAnnotation = [[AddressAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:location];
    [mapView addAnnotation:addAnnotation];

    [mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
    [mapView regionThatFits:region];
    //[mapView selectAnnotation:mLodgeAnnotation animated:YES];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [viewController release];

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your test device is connected to the internet?

Comment: I've tried with only a nib and the two files no code at all. Map View in the nib and '#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>' in the .h file. It is not showing the landscape on the device

Comment: It was a device problem, thx for all yours replays

Comment: did you find a solution ? it works on my ipad but a blank page  appears on  my iphone

Answer (score 0):

have you made sure the map delgate has been set? Make sure you add the delagate to the header and on the view did load mapkit.delagte=self;

Dan

Comment: it's not the delegate... the map view is showing, but the drawing is not appearing. it's like the device has no internet :S